# In JSX how do I set a className as string + {prop}

Tags: reactjs

I'm a bit new to React and trying to set a className as string + prop. But I'm not sure how to do it and whether that is the best practice.

So what I'm trying to do, and it's obviously not working, is this:

```
<a data-featherlight='string' + {this.props.data.imageUrl}>
```

How would I go about writing this?

Answer (score 243, accepted):

You can use string concatenation

```
<a data-featherlight={'string' + this.props.data.imageUrl}>
```

or use [`Template strings`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) new ES2015 feature

```
<a data-featherlight={ `string${this.props.data.imageUrl}` }>
```

Comment: I would like to concatenate `fontawesome` string like `faTwitter` from `fa` and `Twitter` for `icon={faTwitter}`. However this does not accept `string`, 'casue it's `IconProp` type. How can we overcome this?

Answer (score 5):

**You can also try it:**

```
<a data-featherlight={'string1' + this.props.data.imageUrl + 'string2'}>
```

or

```
<a data-featherlight={ `string1 ${this.props.data.imageUrl} string2` }>
```

**If you are using Link component then you can concatenation like this:**

```
<Link to={`getting-started/${this.props.message}`}>
     <h1>Under {this.props.message}/-</h1>
</Link>
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, first:

```
<a data-featherlight={'your string' + this.props.data.imageUrl}>
```

Second:

```
<a data-featherlight={`your string ${this.props.data.imageUrl}`}>
```

Comment: How is this different from the accepted answer from 2016?