# ES6 Template Literals(Template String) in React of ASP.NET Core project

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, ecmascript-6, template-literals

I have used React in ASP.NET Core project where I stuck in one place where I need one part of classname should be dynamic and another part should be constant. Template Literals can achieve my usecase but I'm not getting how can I use it in my project. What I wanna achieve is given below

```
<Button
    size="lg"
    className=`${this.state.btnColor} p-3 m-3`
    onClick={() => this.showForm()}
>
```

In above example - `btnColor` will contain color which I'll change as per users interaction but padding and margin should be kept as it is. When I have used above code, it has thrown an error.

I know about CSS `background` attribute but I want to use bootstrap class names. When I'll change state of `btnColor` then button color will change.

How can I use ES6 Template Literal feature in React of ASP.NET Core project?

Comment: Should it be `className={\`${this.state.btnColor} p-3 m-3\`}`?

Comment: Absolutely. Thanks, it worked perfectly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In JSX how do I set a className as string + {prop}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35148695/in-jsx-how-do-i-set-a-classname-as-string-prop) and [template string of es6 in attribute of react component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44426933)

Comment: You can [accept the duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250922/can-we-clarify-to-the-op-that-their-question-is-not-yet-closed-and-the-duplicate/250930#250930) by clicking on *"That solved my problem"*

Comment: Yes I have accepted it.